# IE 7 Left Center Right align without tables

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am have 3 divs

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="center">center</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>    
</div>
```

and i need to have them in aligned horizontally 
in IE7 the right one jumps to the next line.
I am using left and right floats ( center is set to display:inline; clear:none;)
I am also staying away from absolute positioning ( but maybe its the only way to do it)
any suggestion on a clever way to achieve this without using tables?
thank you

Comment: so far what i have tried that works better is set #container to have position : relative; and #center to have position : absolute; that way the center floats on top of the two others...not ideal but the best i could do for now. any other suggestions are welcome

Comment: Are you searching for the [`holy grail`](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/)?

Comment: LOL.... one of those painful IE experiences :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a litle example: http://jsfiddle.net/K7G3C/

Answer (score 1):

use `float: left;` in all div in css. no need `display:inline;`.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="center">center</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>    
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#container div{
   float: left;
   width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: thanks Arif, the problem with this method is that i need to assign a width..while i want the center to be flexible with its content ( kind of like  the way a table would behave)